# How can I separate string?

Tags: android

When I'm printing String, in logcat I'm getting like this:

```
{"urldetails":"aHR0cDydmljZXMvfmh0dHA6Ly80Ny45MS4xMTUuMjEyL1NDTVMvd2ViL2FwcF9zYm94LnBocA==","customer":"NH4fjIyOTF+RHIuQWZhcmdoZXNl"}
```

In this 3 things I want store in separately, one is urldetails, one iscustomer before + and 3rd one is after + String.

How can I do that?

When I tried, I'm getting indexoutofbounf exception

Comment: this a JSON object Did you try ? 
`JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("YOUR STRING VARIABLE HERE")
Log.d("TAG"," res  "+jsonObject.getString("urldetails"))`

Comment: please elaborate more on your problem. Whatever you tried to post on the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the values with JSONObject.

```java
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(your-string);
String urldetails = json.getString("urldetails");
String[] customers = json.getString("customer").split("\\+");
String customer1 = customers[0]; //customer before +
String customer2 = customers[1]; //customer after +
```

Comment: I'm getting problem in this line, it is saying convert to string

Comment: String[] customers it it telling to string instead of array compiler error

Comment: Edited again with escaping

Comment: Thank you so much dear for very quick help.

Comment: Use `split()`. See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

Comment: I just added extra h for http

Comment: just tell no how

Answer (score 0):

try use kotlin

```
yourModel = Gson().fromJson(this, T::class.java)
yourModel.customer.substringAfter("+")
yourModel.customer.substringBefore("+")
```

Comment: please provide in java